# JSF (Container Managed Security) Group Roles

Tags: security, jsf

For a JSF application running on JBoss 4.2 with JSF 1.2, Container Managed Security and EJB 3.0 I'm looking for a solution to have several roles combined in one role. For example:

- Roles: IT-Support, Phone-Support, Technical-Support, Deliver-Support

Now, I want to specify one role which includes for example three of these roles:

- Role: Senior-Suppoert (IT-Support, Technical-Support, Deliver-Support)

Is this possible with the container managed security and Jboss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible with container managed authorization facilities.

Even more, role inheritance is considered [bad design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model). Just don't do that. Depending on the concrete functional requirements, you could either auto-create the three additional roles when you specify the "global" role (or the other way round), or create a helper/utility method/function to check if the given user has all the three roles (thus, without creating an additional role).

Comment: Thank you. It's a workaround but well, I have to use the container managed security...